# Write tar file to buffer with python

Tags: python, tar

I want to get the data of tar.gz I created

In this example I create the tar.gz file, and then read the content

```
import tarfile
with tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz', 'w:gz') as f:
    f.add("/home/chris/.zshrc")

with open ('/tmp/test.tar.gz','rb') as f:
    data = f.read()
```

I there any short and clean way? I dpn't need the tar.gz file, only the data

Comment: Please fix your code with correct indentation

Comment: I am unsure what your question is. Do you mean that you don't want to create a tar file, just read one?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I'm all for closing questions when they are *complete* duplicates of already asked and answered questions. But as is so often the case, we are often so eager to close a question when there is an answer that addresses only a part of the question. Yes, the link tells how *in general* how you can write a string or byte string to an in-memory buffer. But does that *completely* answer the the OP's question? NO. The OP has to now arrange for the `tarfile` module to write its output to a BytesIO instance. Is such a thing even possible? If so, how? I didn't find the answer at that link.

Answer (score 1):

Use an in-memory buffer by specifying to `tarfile` the `fileobj` argument that is an `io.BytesIO` instance:

```
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO


buf = BytesIO()    
with tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz', 'w:gz', fileobj=buf) as f:
    f.add("/home/chris/.zshrc")

data = buf.getvalue()
print(len(data))
```

Or you can do:

```
import tarfile
from io import BytesIO


buf = BytesIO() 
with tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz', 'w:gz', fileobj=buf) as f:
    f.add("/home/chris/.zshrc")
   
buf.seek(0, 0) # reset pointer back to the start of the buffer
with tarfile.open('/tmp/test.tar.gz', 'r:gz', fileobj=buf) as f:
    print(f.getmembers())
```

Comment: Thank you , I loved the first way, but still I need to put path into `tarfile.open` ? even fake path?

Comment: There *is* a path being specified in the `tarfile.open` call -- it is ''/tmp/test.tar.gz'. What's the problem?